# How to change seekbar length programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, seekbar

I currently have a seekbar within an alertdialog. I'm trying to make the alerdialog longer, but I've used seek.setminheight and seek.setminwidth and with both it doesn't change in size. what should I use to change its size? It has to be done programmatically btw.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogSB = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                dialogSB.setTitle("Alert box");
                                dialogSB.setMessage("Text");
                                LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(context);
                                linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                                linear.setMinimumWidth(400);
                                TextView text = new TextView(context);
                                text.setText("Hello");
                                text.setPadding(30,30,30,30);
                                SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(context);
                                seek.setMax(14);
                                seek.setMinimumWidth(400);
                                seek.setMinimumHeight(400);
                                linear.addView(text);
                                linear.addView(seek);
                                dialogSB.setView(linear);
                                dialogSB.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had the `layout` set to `horizontal`, when it should have been set to `vertical`.